# How to export an opaque type in C

Tags: mysql, c, module, portability

I'm writing an application that involves a MySQL database, and I want to have all database-related operations in one (or more, in a future) specific files. I need to export a database connection ID to the other modules so they can use the services of the DB module.

Ideally, this would be.
(in db.h)

```
typedef ????? dbconn_t
```

in other files

```
dbconn_t = db_newconnection(...);
```

The MySQL type for db connections is called MYSQL, so I was inclined to write

```
typedef MYSQL *dbconn;
```

But to do this, I would need to include mysql.h in my own db.h, exporting tons of functions and other types to the rest of the project.

Some solutions come to mind:

- Export an int type and keep a table for mapping ints to MYSQL pointers
- Export a void pointer and type cast in every call in database handling code

Both seem pretty bad. Any ideas to help this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could encapsulate your data ID into a struct type.

For example, in your private headers you could have something like

```
struct dbconn {
     int id;
};
```

While in the header you export it as

```
struct dbconn;
typedef struct dbconn *dbconn_t;
```

Comment: Seems like the best way to go. Encapsulate the data inside a struct and use pointers to that type everywhere. Thanks!